# Как преобразовать тип одного элемента из массива?

Tags: c, преобразование-типов

Использовал такой метод:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  char gar[3] = { '3', '6', '9' };
  int far = atoi(gar[0]);
  printf( "%d", far);

  return 0;
}
```

выдаёт ошибку

> assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Но даже с переводом я не понял, что это значит и как это исправить.

Если массив `gar` одноэлементный, то код работает правильно и выводит на экран цифру `3`.

Что делаю не так и какие ещё есть способы решения этой задачи?

Comment: `int far = gar[0] - '0';`

Comment: @Harry, работает. Благодарю) Но способ выглядит каким-то костыльным.

Comment: Почему костыльным? Если вы используете цифры, то для преобразования в число стандартный корректный способ... Самый быстрый :) Хотите странного? преобразовывайте в строку...

Answer (score 1):

[`atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) работает со строкой. Один символ туда передавать нельзя. Надо передавать указатель на строку - массив символов, завершающийся нулём.

Например `buffer` - строка из двух символов. Первый - пробел, второй - `'\0'`. В первый символ кладётся цифра из массива, весь буфер передаётся в `atoi`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char gar[] = {'3', '6', '9'};
    char buffer[] = " ";
    buffer[0] = gar[0];
    printf("%d\n", atoi(buffer));
}
```

**P.S.** Способ из комментария (`gar[0] - '0'`) не костыльный. Язык гарантирует, что это будет работать везде и очень быстро. Обычно его и применяют.